# SQL group rows by Top 3 and other. (Revenue by Top 3 cities by state and then other)

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

so I have a query that gives my every city, it's corresponding state, and the value my customers spent in that city.

I would like to define top 3 by the TotalCustomerValue per city.

The query is a bit more complicated than that, but this is the core of it:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    --*
    LTRIM(RTRIM(cs.City)) City
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(cs.State)) State

    ,SUM(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) TotalCustomerValue
    ,SUM(cs.TotalOrdersBase) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) TotalOrders

    FROM ( -- This table gives full customer information per customer.
    )CSS
```

What I want to do is create a table where it has the top 3 cities of every state, and then an other row (which will be treated like every other row) that will be the sum of all the other cities. So the total table would have 200 lines, (50*4).

I am trying to do something with row number, but I can't seem to work it

```
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State Order by sum(CS.TotalCustomerValueOverBase)) rowNr
```

Then I could try to sum all rownumbers greater than 3.

Does anyone have any ideas?

And then I'm assuming SSRS when I want to create visuals with this data, I can just create like a filter on all rows with the keyword Other, right?

Here is my full query (with an attempt to implement Gordon's solution)

```
SELECT 
(case when CSS.seqnum <= 3 then city else 'Others' end) as city,
(case when seqnum <= 3 then state end) as state
sum(TotalCustomerValue) as TotalCustomerValue,
sum(TotalOrders) as TotalOrders

FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    --*
    LTRIM(RTRIM(cs.City)) City
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(cs.State)) State

    ,right(left(lat, len(lat) -1),len(lat) -2) lat -- the lat and long are wrapped in quotes
    ,right(left(lng, len(lng) -1),len(lng) -2) lng -- so i have to do the left right to get rid of them. 

    ,SUM(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) TotalCustomerValue
    ,SUM(cs.TotalOrdersBase) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) TotalOrders
    --,SUM(cs.TotalQuantityOverBase) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) TotalQuantity

    ,CONVERT(float, right(left(population_proper, len(population_proper) -1),len(population_proper) -2)) population_proper

    ,CAST(
        SUM(cs.TotalOrdersBase) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) 
        /
        NULLIF(convert(float, right(left(population_proper, len(population_proper) -1),len(population_proper) -2)),0)--*100 
    as decimal(10,4)) AS OrderDensityPercent

    ,SUM(cs.BrandNewCustomer) over (partition by     cs.City, cs.State) BrandNewCustomers
    ,SUM(cs.RecurringCustomer) over (partition by    cs.City, cs.State) RecurringCustomers
    ,SUM(cs.ReactivatedCustomer) over (partition by  cs.City, cs.State) ReactivatedCustomers

    ,row_number() over (partition by ltrim(rtrim(cs.State)) order by sum(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) desc) as seqnum

    FROM ( -- This table gives full customer information per customer.
        SELECT 
        CC.CustomerEmail
        ,CC.Month Month
        ,CONCAT(CC.Year, '-', CASE WHEN CC.Month < 10 then '0' else '' end, CC.Month) Date


        ,CASE WHEN  
            (   ISNULL(CC.TotalOrdersCustomerBase,0) >= 1
            AND ISNULL(RC.TotalOrdersRecurringBase,0) = 0
            AND ISNULL(LC.TotalOrdersLifetimeBase,0) = 0) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END BrandNewCustomer

        ,CASE WHEN  
            (   ISNULL(CC.TotalOrdersCustomerBase,0)  >= 1 
            AND ISNULL(RC.TotalOrdersRecurringBase,0) >= 1)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RecurringCustomer

        ,CASE WHEN  
            (   ISNULL(CC.TotalOrdersCustomerBase,0) >= 1 
            AND ISNULL(RC.TotalOrdersRecurringBase,0) = 0
            AND ISNULL(LC.TotalOrdersLifetimeBase,0) >= 1) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ReactivatedCustomer

        ,ISNULL(CC.TotalCustomerValueOverCustomerBase,0) TotalCustomerValueOverCustomerBase
        ,ISNULL(CC.TotalOrdersCustomerBase,0) TotalOrdersCustomerBase
        ,ISNULL(CC.TotalQuantityOverCustomerBase,0) TotalQuantityOverCustomerBase

        ,ISNULL(RC.TotalCustomerValueOverRecurringBase,0) TotalCustomerValueOverRecurringBase
        ,ISNULL(RC.TotalOrdersRecurringBase,0) TotalOrdersRecurringBase
        ,ISNULL(RC.TotalQuantityOverRecurringBase,0) TotalQuantityOverRecurringBase

        ,ISNULL(LC.TotalCustomerValueOverLifetimeBase,0) TotalCustomerValueOverLifetimeBase
        ,ISNULL(LC.TotalOrdersLifetimeBase,0) TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
        ,ISNULL(LC.TotalQuantityOverLifetimeBase,0) TotalQuantityOverLifetimeBase

        ,ISNULL(FC.TotalCustomerValueOverBase,0) TotalCustomerValueOverBase
        ,ISNULL(FC.TotalOrdersBase,0) TotalOrdersBase
        ,ISNULL(FC.TotalQuantityOverBase,0) TotalQuantityOverBase

        ,ISNULL(CC.TotalCustomersOverCustomerBase,0) TotalCustomersOverCustomerBase
        ,ISNULL(RC.TotalCustomersOverRecurringBase,0) TotalCustomersOverRecurringBase
        ,ISNULL(LC.TotalCustomersOverLifetimeBase,0) TotalCustomersOverLifetimeBase
        ,ISNULL(FC.TotalCustomersOverBase,0) TotalCustomersOverBase

        ,CC.City
        ,CC.State
        ,CC.CountryCode

        From
        (
            SELECT 
            C.CustomerEmail
            ,C.Month
            ,C.Year
            ,C.TotalCustomersOverCustomerBase
            ,C.TotalCustomerValueOverCustomerBase
            ,C.TotalOrdersCustomerBase
            ,C.TotalQuantityOverCustomerBase
            ,C.City
            ,C.State
            ,C.CountryCode
            FROM
            #CustomerBase C
            WHERE C.OrderCountCustomerBase = 1 -- This makes it return only the first row of a customer with multiple purchases.
            --and  TotalOrdersCustomerBase = TotalQuantityOverCustomerBase 
        ) CC

        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
            R.CustomerEmail
            ,R.TotalCustomersOverRecurringBase
            ,R.TotalCustomerValueOverRecurringBase
            ,R.TotalOrdersRecurringBase
            ,R.TotalQuantityOverRecurringBase
            FROM
            #RecurringBase R
            WHERE R.OrderCountRecurringBase = 1
        ) RC ON CC.CustomerEmail = RC.CustomerEmail

        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
            L.CustomerEmail
            ,L.TotalCustomersOverLifetimeBase
            ,L.TotalCustomerValueOverLifetimeBase
            ,L.TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
            ,L.TotalQuantityOverLifetimeBase
            FROM
            #LifetimeBase L
            WHERE L.OrderCountLifetimeBase = 1
        ) LC ON CC.CustomerEmail = LC.CustomerEmail

        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
            F.CustomerEmail
            ,F.TotalCustomersOverBase
            ,F.TotalCustomerValueOverBase
            ,F.TotalOrdersBase
            ,F.TotalQuantityOverBase
            FROM
            #FullBase F
            WHERE F.OrderCountBase = 1
        ) FC ON CC.CustomerEmail = FC.CustomerEmail

    ) Cs --Customers

    LEFT JOIN [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[uscities] Ci ON cs.City = right(left(ci.city_ascii, len(ci.city_ascii) -1),len(ci.city_ascii) -2) and cs.State = right(left(ci.state_id, len(ci.state_id) -1),len(ci.state_id) -2)

    WHERE 
    LAT IS NOT NULL 
    AND LNG IS NOT NULL

    group by ltrim(rtrim(cs.City)), ltrim(rtrim(cs.State))


)CSS


Where CAST(CSS.LAT AS FLOAT) > 20 AND CAST(CSS.LNG AS FLOAT) > -120

group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then city else 'Others' end),
(case when seqnum <= 3 then state end)

ORDER BY TotalCustomerValue DESC
```

Comment: How do you define "top 3"?

Comment: I've added that information, by TotalCustomerValue

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation and some conditional logic:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 3 then city else 'Others' end) as city,
       state,
       sum(TotalCustomerValue) as TotalCustomerValue,
       sum(TotalOrders) as TotalOrders
from (select ltrim(rtrim(cs.City)) as City, ltrim(rtrim(cs.State)) as State,
             sum(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) as TotalCustomerValue,
             sum(cs.TotalOrdersBase) as TotalOrders,
             row_number() over (partition by ltrim(rtrim(cs.State)) order by sum(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) desc) as seqnum
      from . . . cs
      group by ltrim(rtrim(cs.City)), ltrim(rtrim(cs.State))
     ) cs
group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then city else 'Others' end),
         (case when seqnum <= 3 then state end)
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment, you can do:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 3 then city else 'Others' end) as city,
       (case when seqnum <= 3 then state end) as state,
       sum(TotalCustomerValue) as TotalCustomerValue,
       sum(TotalOrders) as TotalOrders
from (select ltrim(rtrim(cs.City)) as City, ltrim(rtrim(cs.State)) as State,
             sum(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) as TotalCustomerValue,
             sum(cs.TotalOrdersBase) as TotalOrders,
             row_number() over (partition by ltrim(rtrim(cs.State)) order by sum(cs.TotalCustomerValueOverBase) desc) as seqnum
      from . . . cs
      group by ltrim(rtrim(cs.City)), ltrim(rtrim(cs.State))
     ) cs
group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then city else 'Others' end),
         state
```

Comment: Gordon, I've tried implementing your solution but I cant seem to get it to work. I've edited my original question to include the full query and my attempt at integrating your code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the group by, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: I got the query to work, but it does all others as one large bucket, I was trying to do an others bucket per state. Would that be possible? https://i.imgur.com/95OYAn7.png

Comment: @Natan . . . You just have to adjust the `GROUP BY`.